# How can I create an offline environment for my PHP Facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website that reads information from a facebook wall. I can happily dump the wall object with var_dump or print_r in to a file but how can i use that data so i can work offline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can't store PHP objects into a database or something. When the script execution is ended, so is the life of your variables.

You could however create a database to store the object's data in.

Comment: Thanks - but I cant believe there isn't an easier way!

Answer (score 0):

No easier way ... 
Or you can use your var_dump, create a file (xml or whatever) than load it back when you need it. But a database is easier in my opinion.